# Formatting SQL rows to a list in python

Tags: python, sql

I have a bunch of SQL rows that I have converted to lists:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
result = cursor.execute(SQLqueries.sql_qry1)

for row in result:
    row_to_list = list(row)
    print(row_to_list)
```

The output of this is lists like:

```
['FreqBand,Frequency,0, 5, 10\r\n1,0.006,16.56,25.15,30.96\r\n']
['FreqBand,Frequency,0, 5, 10\r\n1,0.006,12.56,15.27,31.90\r\n']
['FreqBand,Frequency,0, 5, 10\r\n1,0.006,16.36,25.15,34.46\r\n']
```

I would like to edit these lists to exclude the first two words and replace the "\r\n" characters with commas. I've tried this to get rid of the 'FreqBand,Frequency':

```
for row in result:
    row_to_list = list(row)
    i = 0
    for each in row_to_list:
        row_to_list[i].replace('FreqBand', '')
        i += 1
    print(row_to_list)
```

but the output of this seems to get rid of half the first list and doesn't edit any of the others. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Which database you're querying against? It's funny because `execute` should not return any value. `result = [list(row) for row in cursor]` should work though

Comment: Why is your query returning the entire row as a single string, instead of separate elements for each column?

Comment: `replace()` returns the new value, it doesn't modify the string in place.

Comment: @Barmar The query is "select cast(MeasurementFile as varchar(max)) from Measurements M", so it's returning one column that is a single string

Comment: That just raises the question of why you're storing this as a single string in the database, rather than splitting it into separate columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the result of `replace()` back to the list element. And use `range()` to get a sequence of numbers instead of incrementing `i` yourself.

```
for row in result:
    row_to_list = list(row)
    for i in range(len(row_to_list)):
        row_to_list[i] = row_to_list[i].replace('FreqBand,Frequency,', '').replace('\r\n', ',')
    print(row_to_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the list below has a size of 1 rather than 8-10 that I assumed when I first saw the question. So initially, please check if that is something you are aware of.

```
['FreqBand,Frequency,0, 5, 10\r\n1,0.006,16.56,25.15,30.96\r\n']
```

In this way, when you iterate over this list with `for each in row_to_list:`, all you will get is the string that has no difference from the string you would get with `row_to_list[0]`.

Secondly, you might want to double check what you are trying to accomplish with the counter i. In the case of manipulating first elements of each list you name as `row_to_list`, all you need to do is to access by index then reassign the variable.

```
for row in result:
    row_to_list = list(row)
    row_to_list[0] = row_to_list[0].replace('FreqBand,Frequency,', '')
    row_to_list[-1] = row_to_list[-1].replace('\r\n', ',')
```